# how to install signalmaster on AWS ec2 isntance

Tags: centos, turn, coturn

I want to install signalmaster on my EC2 instance for CentOS, in a similar way to the method given in the instruction given [here](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster).
What are the steps to install signaling server for clients to connect and do signaling for WebRTC on AWS?